# Is there a way to make a function take action immediately when it's done?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I have a `SIGN IN` button, that `onclick` calls a function `login()`. Inside `login()` i call 2 functions:

```
function login()
{
    signin();
    statistics_table();
    return false;
}
```

`signin();` performs the actual signing in (`$_SESSION['name']=$username;`) (`ajax`), and `statistics_table();` prints out a table related to the user or a text saying **"please login to see your statistics"** (in case the signing in didn't work) (`ajax` as well).

Problem is `statistics_table()` always prints out **"please login..."**. It's as if `signin()` hasn't performed the actual signing in yet. Apparently it performs it only after the function `login()` returns.

So is there a way to make `signin()` apply its actions just after it finishes?

I also tried making the button call the functions `signin()` and `statistics_table()` one after another, like this:

`<input type="submit" value="Sign In" onclick="signin(); statistics_table();">`

but this way when i click the button it kinda reloads the page (again, i need it to be ajax).

Thanks in advance

**edit:**

Here is the implementation of `signin()`:

```
function signin()
{
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var pw= document.getElementById('password').value;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("Test").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","members.php?name="+name+ "&password="+pw,true);
    xmlhttp.send(); 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The first `A` in `AJAX` stands for `Asynchronous`. It doesn't wait to complete before moving onto the next instruction. Post the inside of your `signin()` function, so we can see how you implemented it. You need a callback to execute when it succeeds, in which `statistics_table()` gets called.

Comment: fair enough. please see edit above...

Comment: move `statistics_table()` inside of your `readystate` evaluation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to move the `statistics_table()` call *inside* the `onreadystatechange` callback for`readyState == 4`, so it is called after successful completion of the user login.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        // You're already writing some output with the XHR response
        document.getElementById("Test").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

        // So no problem writing a little more in the user's table:
        statistics_table();
    }
}
```

And the caller `login()` is then reduced to:

```
function login()
{
    signin();
    return false;
}
```

A further issue: I note that you are attempting to initiate a `POST` request, but in fact you are passing the parameters in the query string, where PHP would receive them as `$_GET`.  Instead of the query string, the parameters belong inside the argument to `.send()`:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","members.php", true);
// Set the correct Content-type header for a POST form
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("name=" + encodeURIComponent(name) + "&password="+encodeURIComponent(pw));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked! But the `xmlhttp.open` and `xmlhttp.send` you suggested didn't work well for me. This way `members.php` always returns `wrong username/password`. Weird. Anyway, seems like i miss some important knowledge about `ajax`. Any recommended website to learn from?

Comment: Maybe that's because in `members.php` i receive `username` and `password` like this: `if(isset($_REQUEST['name']) && isset($_REQUEST['password'])){...}` ?

Comment: The `.open(), .send()` had faulty arguments as I copy/pasted the `true` 3rd arg (`async=true`) from `.open()` into `.send()`, sorry.  I rather like the book Head First AJAX if you are just getting started. Of course, a library like jQuery will abstract lots of this away if you have other uses for it, but for AJAX alone doing it manually isn't too hard once you understand how it should work.

Comment: `$_REQUEST` will receive either `$_GET` or `$_POST`, but you don't want to send them in `$_GET` since that will result in your users passwords ending up in your web server access log.

Comment: Yes i understand the issue about `$_GET` and `$_POST`. Anyway, also after the edit, i always get "wrong username/password". In the network tab i see that it called `members.php` without any arguments.

Comment: @AlaaM. You won't see the args in the network tab because they are part of the POST body. If you examine the request sent by clicking on it from the network tab, you should be able to see the full headers and post body, and that's where your values are.

Comment: You're right. I understand now. So I see them there (they look correct) but the signing in doesn't occur. Now I figured that the `if statement` that fails is `if(isset($_REQUEST['name']) && isset($_REQUEST['password']))`

Comment: Weird... the response is `ARRAY()`. What does that mean?! Could it be the variables i'm defining before the `if statement` ?

Comment: It means you have no POST values received (or none handled by `$_REQUEST`) Do you see vales in `print_r($_POST);`? Did you get values before when you were sending them in the query string (to `$_GET`) .

Comment: If i leave the `open` and `send` as they were, (and of course the function call inside as you said), all works perfect. Anyway `print_r($POST)` also gives `Array()`

Comment: Ah, I see it - you need `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` after `.open()`, before `.send()` for the `$_POST` to be received

Comment: What are all those strange arguments though...?

Comment: What arguments? The content-type header? `x-www-form-urlencoded` is the content-type a browser would send for a POST form action.